# Sort array by cost and name

Tags: php, arrays, web-services

```
  {
m: "1",
total: "6",
r: [
{
job_id: "472",
category: "plumbing",
job_cost: "350",
posted_on: "17 Dec 2015",
completed_on: "17 Dec 2015",
job_final_status: "1"
},
{
job_id: "459",
category: "electrical",
job_cost: "600",
posted_on: "16 Dec 2015",
completed_on: "16 Dec 2015",
job_final_status: "1"
},
{
job_id: "457",
category: "electrical",
job_cost: "1000",
posted_on: "16 Dec 2015",
completed_on: "16 Dec 2015",
job_final_status: "1"
},
{
job_id: "456",
category: "carpentry",
job_cost: "350",
posted_on: "16 Dec 2015",
completed_on: "16 Dec 2015",
job_final_status: "1"
},
{
job_id: "454",
category: "electrical",
job_cost: "450",
posted_on: "16 Dec 2015",
completed_on: "16 Dec 2015",
job_final_status: "1"
},
{
job_id: "433",
category: "plumbing",
job_cost: "400",
posted_on: "15 Dec 2015",
completed_on: "15 Dec 2015",
job_final_status: "1"
}
]
}
```

Above is response of my web-service.
I want array ('r') result like, firstly sort by category name, and if category name are same, then result for that category should be sorted by `job_cost` higher to lower.

So my desired result is as below:

```
{
m: "1",
total: "6",
r: [
{
job_id: "456",
category: "carpentry",
job_cost: "350",
posted_on: "16 Dec 2015",
completed_on: "16 Dec 2015",
job_final_status: "1"
},
{
job_id: "457",
category: "electrical",
job_cost: "1000",
posted_on: "16 Dec 2015",
completed_on: "16 Dec 2015",
job_final_status: "1"
},
{
job_id: "459",
category: "electrical",
job_cost: "600",
posted_on: "16 Dec 2015",
completed_on: "16 Dec 2015",
job_final_status: "1"
},
{
job_id: "454",
category: "electrical",
job_cost: "450",
posted_on: "16 Dec 2015",
completed_on: "16 Dec 2015",
job_final_status: "1"
},
{
job_id: "433",
category: "plumbing",
job_cost: "400",
posted_on: "15 Dec 2015",
completed_on: "15 Dec 2015",
job_final_status: "1"
},
{
job_id: "472",
category: "plumbing",
job_cost: "350",
posted_on: "17 Dec 2015",
completed_on: "17 Dec 2015",
job_final_status: "1"
}
]
}
```

Comment: while fetching these records from database, that time itself you can sort right?

Comment: You shoulf use `uasort()`

Comment: Use `json_decode($data, true)` to get an associative array. You can then provide a custom sorting function to `usort()` to sort your array how you want itr

Comment: yes, but from database i can sort by category name only, or by job_cost only.. these can not fulfill my desired answer..

Comment: why the db allows only sorting by one column?!

Comment: @RoyalBg being an web service call, maybe he can't access the queries which returns the results.. maybe there is just an parameter which allows you to order by a column or another..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would solve your problem.

First you decode the info with:

```
 $r = json_decode($yourJSONstring);
```

Then you can make an empty array that you will fill with occurring categories:

```
$occurring = array();
```

then you can combine the arrays with the same category by looping them like so:

```
foreach ($r as $item) {
    if (isset($occurring [$item['category']])) {
        $occurring [$item['category']][] = $item;
    } else {
        $occurring [$item['category']] = array();
        $occurring [$item['category']][] = $item;
    }
}
```

Then you can sort those like this:

```
foreach ($occurring as $key => $item) {
    $occurring[$key] = Classname::array_sort_by_column($item,"job_cost",SORT_DESC);
}
```

With a function like this:

```
static public function sort_by_column($sortArray, $columnName, $sortDirection = SORT_ASC) {
    $sortCol = array();

    foreach ($sortArray as $key => $row) {
      $sortCol [$key] = $row[$columnName];
    }

    array_multisort($sortCol , $sortDirection, $sortArray);

    return $sortArray;
}
```

I Hope this solves your problem :)

Comment: thank you, that separated each aray element as category name.. but no problem, i will manage.. thank you..

Answer (score 1):

First, you fire a `MYSQL` query for sort by `FILED` after that you should use the array sort by value accordingly `uasort()` function.
Try these, may be it will be help you..

Answer (score 1):

First, you fire a MYSQL query for sort by FILED after that you should use the array sort by value accordingly uasort() function. Try these, may be it will be help you..